# How to share variables between classes in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am expanding my JS knowledge by building custom libraries on-top of jQuery/JS and the classes have to interact between each other. I am coming from PHP, so there I could use static variables, but have no idea in JS. Here is an example of what I want:

```
var A = function() {
    this.myPublicVar = "thisShouldBePrintedFromClassB";
}

A.prototype = {
    showMyVar : function() {alert(this.myPublicVar);} // This gets triggered on direct access.
}

var B = function() {}
B.prototype = {
    // I have no idea how to to access A.myPublicVar
}
```

Anyone could provide me with simple tutorial or anything?

PS: I have just started to expand my JS knowledge, have used JS/jQuery for easy design purposes (using selectors and building data validators and etc.)

Comment: `B` needs to inherit from `A` if you want to access that property.

Comment: B.prototype = new A(); something like this
read this it may be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15843660/inheritance-within-javascript

Comment: and how should I use multiple classes lets say like in a framework(ie. multiple inheritance)

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15798417/1026459

Comment: The problem is that you're thinking in classes. JavaScript prototype model can sort of imitate class inheritance but not the other way around. Think about modules, that's the JavaScript way.

Comment: try this
var foo = (function(foo) {
  // put all code here...
}(foo || {}));
and you can read about module patterns from here... http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html

Comment: @elclanrs ok give me an example of the simple modular usage

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use inheritance to access the variable.

```
var A = function() {
    this.myPublicVar = "thisShouldBePrintedFromClassB";
}

A.prototype = {
    showMyVar : function() {alert(this.myPublicVar);} // This gets triggered on direct access.
}

var B = function() {}
B.prototype = new A();
B.prototype.print = function(){
  alert(this.myPublicVar);
}

var b = new B();
b.print();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var A = function() {
    this.myPublicVar = "thisShouldBePrintedFromClassB";
}

A.prototype = {
    showMyVar : function() {alert(this.myPublicVar);} // This gets triggered on direct access.
}

var B = function() {}
B.prototype = new A();  //This is what you're missing.

console.log(B.prototype.myPublicVar);
```